# How does one increase reputation on stack exchange

Tags: discussion

I know that is not directly related to the theme of the site. However, upon registration I am unable to comment or vote on questions without reaching a specific threshold. Is it normal for new members to start with 1 reputation? If so does this mean that every person should start their journey on Stack Exchange by either asking a question or answering one?

Also since it seems that privileges depend on the reputation of the account, are there any specific tasks that the site expects from the users so as to maintain the site standards. For example I can understand why allowing only reputed users to vote on questions is a must. This prevents fake accounts from being created just for the purpose of voting and what not. However, what other benefits are to be expected?

Comment: You would need to ask or answer a Matter Modeling question first. This will allow you to participate on meta.mattermodeling.stackexchange.com where you can ask questions about how the site works.

Answer (score 3):

For an in-depth guide, I would look to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) on Meta StackExchange describing what rep is and how to get it in great detail.

StackExchange places a number of site functions behind rep thresholds. By making positive contributions to the community (e.g asking good questions, providing good answers, editing posts), your rep will increase, earning you more privileges on the site. Higher rep should hopefully indicate a greater familiarity with the site and a track record of making positive contributions, suggesting the user can be trusted with more of the site's functionality.

At the lowest rep levels, you can still ask and answer questions, but can't do other things like comment on, vote on, edit, or review posts. As you noted, this helps block spam account from causing damage, but it also prevents well meaning new users from causing damage by using certain site tools before they understand how they work or how the community usually handles things.

Comment: Thanks for the information